# Assign chef roles to layer/instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef, opsworks

I'm trying to get the following cookbook running in OpsWorks: https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash/

Following their documentation I have to assign roles to my server(s) to get stuff running.
They also gave examples of roles in the wiki.
But I'm stuck on how to apply these roles to an instance oder a whole layer in my OpsWorks setup.
Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a service role or default profile, when you are first creating your OpsWorks Stack there is a selection list for what role you want to use called "Default IAM instance profile".

[image]